# Removing subdocument in mongoose

Tags: node.js, mongodb, express, mongoose, subdocument

I have a model like this:

```
 const Screen = new Schema(
    {
        userId: [
            {
                type: ObjectId,
                default: null
            }
        ],
        contents: [
            {
                content: {
                    type: ObjectId,
                    ref: "Content",
                    default: null
                }
            }
        ],
    },
    { strict: false }
);
```

and i want to remove a content in contents subcdoc and i wrote it like this:

```
screenModel
    .find({ screenCode: screenCode })
    .lean()
    .exec()
    .then(screen =>
    {
        const newScreen = screen;
        newScreen.contents.id(_id).remove();
        screenModel.replaceOne(screen, newScreen);
        return newScreen;
    })
```

but it returns me that error:

> "Error: Cannot read property 'id' of undefined
>     at APIError.ExtendableError (D:\Projelerim\React\adonis-api-v1\workspace\dist\api\helpers\APIError.js:35:11)
>     at new APIError (D:\Projelerim\React\adonis-api-v1\workspace\dist\api\helpers\APIError.js:63:101)
>     at D:\Projelerim\React\adonis-api-v1\workspace\dist\config\express.js:129:20
>     at Layer.handle_error (D:\Projelerim\React\adonis-api-v1\workspace\
>   ode_modules\express\lib\router\layer.js:71:5)
>     at trim_prefix (D:\Projelerim\React\adonis-api-v1\workspace\
>   ode_modules\express\lib\router\index.js:315:13)
>     at D:\Projelerim\React\adonis-api-v1\workspace\
>   ode_modules\express\lib\router\index.js:284:7
>     at Function.process_params (D:\Projelerim\React\adonis-api-v1\workspace\
>   ode_modules\express\lib\router\index.js:335:12)
>     at next (D:\Projelerim\React\adonis-api-v1\workspace\
>   ode_modules\express\lib\router\index.js:275:10)
>     at D:\Projelerim\React\adonis-api-v1\workspace\
>   ode_modules\express\lib\router\index.js:635:15
>     at Immediate.next (D:\Projelerim\React\adonis-api-v1\workspace\
>   ode_modules\express\lib\router\index.js:260:14)
>     at Immediate._onImmediate (D:\Projelerim\React\adonis-api-v1\workspace\
>   ode_modules\express\lib\router\index.js:635:15)
>     at runCallback (timers.js:706:11)
>     at tryOnImmediate (timers.js:676:5)
>     at processImmediate (timers.js:658:5)
>     at process.topLevelDomainCallback (domain.js:121:23)

Schema looks like this:

```
"contents":[  
  {  
     "content":{  
        "$oid":"5c38a45c7bb5f232d4c3233c"
     },
     "_id":{  
        "$oid":"5c38ad1a994d6b436826778d"
     }
  },
  {  
     "content":{  
        "$oid":"5c38a45c7bb5f232d4c3233c"
     },
     "_id":{  
        "$oid":"5c38ad3d994d6b436826778e"
     }
  }

]
```

What is the wrong with this code? I have tried changing id() to pull() and its also gives error  Please help me :(

Answer (score 0):

I hope you know how lean works [`.lean()`](https://mongoosejs.com/docs/api.html#query_Query-lean).

> Documents returned from queries with the lean option enabled are plain javascript objects, not MongooseDocuments. They have no save method, getters/setters or other Mongoose magic applied.

Debugging your error,

> Cannot read property 'id' of undefined

Obviously, it crashes in this moment `newScreen.contents.id`
Please, add `console.log()` to verify if `screen` received in `then` is what you're looking for.

IMHO, `screen` is `Array` which contains your screens, so, you have to iterate it.
Like this:

```
for (const sc of screen) { ...your logic with removing }
```

Comment: i used console.log() and it finds the screen. Also remove the lean() function and it does not changed again give the error "id property of undefined "

Comment: Also consol.log() gives the content like this: contents: [ [Object], [Object] ],
    __v: 0 } ]

Comment: @MuratÇELİK as you see, there is no `id` in `contents`, to make it work you have to have result like this `contents: { id: 'foo' }`. Now your contents have Array, and of course code can't find `id` property

Comment: @MuratÇELİK maybe you're looking for data in `contents`, so, for example, you can look for `id` in contents like this `contents[0].id`. But, I don't know how your schema looks

Comment: I added schema looks like in the database. Yes when console.log(JSON.stringify(screen.contents)), it is undefined. It cant pull the content i think...